# Pass element id in a directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive to copy same text to clipboard

```
mainApp.directive('ngCopyable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link:link
    };
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click',function(){
            var text = document.getElementById('id-my-div');
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(text);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');

            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            //console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        });
    }

});
```

and it's working. I use this directive in a icon

```
<span ng-copyable>
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-copy"></i>
</span>
```

When I click the icon the text inside the div with id `id-my-div` is succefully copied. The problem is that the id is not dynamic. In this way only that element will be copied. Is is possibile change the directive passing the id of the element i want copy?

Comment: do put a data attribute on the item with the id of the item you want to copy. Than read that data attribute

Comment: Can you please explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any attribute in your directive

```
<span ng-copyable>
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-copy" elementId="myId"></i>
</span>
```

and in your directive your can get via

```
var id = element.attrs('elementId')
```